# Choose endpoint to send request if any field of the page was changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Consider we have SPA.
SPA consists of several dynamic pages.
Also there are a form for each page.

I need to save data once any field was changed (for example user types something to the input and we need immediately).

The main problem is that **some fields must send data to one endpoint, and some fields sends data to another endpoint**.

Also, if some field was changed, there is a $watch for it in controller, and controller sets some value to another field, and these change also need to be saved.

What I can do in that situation? There are many fields, so I don't want to set a $watch for each field.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). It's difficult to show code since you didn't post any, but using ngChange would allow you to make things as general or as granular as you need - A set of inputs could use the same `ng-change` function or you can have an `ng-change` function for a single input field.

Wire up inputs in "group one" to use `groupOneChanged`.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="somethingAwesomeForSure" ng-change="groupOneChanged()">
<input type="text" ng-model="somethingElse" ng-change="groupOneChanged()">
```

Wire up inputs in "group two" to use `groupTwoChanged` and so on.

```
$scope.groupOneChanged = function() {
  // make your api call for group one
};

$scope.groupTwoChanged = function() {
  // make your api call for group two
};
```